# Spark 2.4 Amazon AWS debugging log

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

Trying to work with Amazon AWS (especially s3a buckets) from Spark v2.4. 
I understand that I need to add logging options for Amazon to see what error is

So I added to `spark/conf/log4.properties` file:

```
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.request=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR
```

but I don't see those logs anywhere :(

What is correct settings to log Amazon connection/process/events from Spark?

**P.S. Spark itself + Hadoop running in EC2 instance - I managed to configure them by myself. It's not an Amazon variant of Spark - it standalone instance that I installed myself.** Sorry for confusion with AWS -it's not a *Amazon managed instance* - it's my own setup

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following values for `spark` `log4.properties`:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=INFO
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

The logs can be found in `Amazon AWS` in the following location in `AWS Console`:

> ```
> -> Amazon EMR 
> -> Clusters (choose the relevant cluster) 
> -> Application History
> -> Application ID (choose relevant app id)
> -> Executors
> -> choose the driver or one of the executors
> -> View logs
> ```

The URI of the raw logs can be found in `Amazon AWS` in the following location in `AWS Console`:

> ```
> -> Amazon EMR 
> -> Clusters (choose the relevant cluster) 
> -> Summary
> -> Log URI
> ```

Comment: Sorry - I didn't say that Spark itself running in EMS or other system from Amazon. I installed it by myself. 2 - I don't see line that says: log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a=DEBUG  - you publish standard Spark log config. It does work ok. I need especiialy Amazon logs

Answer (score 0):

When you create cluster, goto advanced option -> General Cluster Settings -> General Option -> Logging checkbox.

Select it and and pass S3 location. You should see logs in that bucket

Answer (score 0):

Normally the logs are configured to go "somewhere" on the local worker nodes, then collected to a shared store afterwards. If things are set up to save to S3 and S3 isn't working, well, you won't see them.

Have a play with [storediag](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore) on the command line before going near spark: it logs to the console and stress tests the connection. If it can't work with S3, Spark isn't going to either.